# View dimensions doesn't alter with iPhone dimension

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have created one view, which I want to use for all iPhone dimensions. So I've set constraints in the view's subviews and its working fine. But when I tried to launch the app in a phone with dimensions less than that of the xib I created, the view projects outside the superview when adding as subview. So now each time when I am adding as subview I have to set the view's frame according to the device's screen dimensions.

I want to know whether there is any other way to resize the view's dimensions in accordance with the device's dimensions, other than setting the view's frame manually.

Comment: Post a screenshot of the auto layout constraints.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the the auto layout in your xib then go to 
editor menu-->Resolve auto layout issues-->ALL views in view-->update constraints. if there is no constraints applied then you can go for add missing constraints and see the difference.

Comment: I have added all the constraints.. That is not it.. the issue is that the main view holding the subviews doesn't resize as we add it as subview.